# Extract characters occurring before one of several forbidden characters

Tags: php, string, text-extraction, blacklist

I want to discard all remaining characters in a string as soon as one of several unwanted characters is encountered.

As soon as a blacklisted character is encountered, the string before that point should be returned.

For instance, if I have an array:

```
$chars = array("a", "b", "c");
```

How would I go through the following string...

```
log dog hat bat
```

...and end up with:

```
log dog h
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [strcspn](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php) function is what you are looking for.

```
<?php

$mask = "abc";

$string = "log dog hat bat";

$result = substr($string,0,strcspn($string,$mask));

var_dump($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly nothing wrong with Vinko's answer and I might be more inclined to recommend that technique in a professional script because regex is likely to perform slower, but purely for a point of difference for researchers, regex could be used.

For the record, to convert the array of `['a', 'b', 'c']` to `abc`, just call `implode($array)` -- an empty glue string is not necessary.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/REAZ3))  -- split in half on first occurrence of a|b|c, then access first element

```
echo preg_split('~[abc]~', $string, 2)[0];
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/f10IR))  -- match leading substring of non-a|b|c characters, then access first element

```
echo preg_match('~^[^abc]+~', $string, $match) ? $match[0] : '';
```

I should state that if any of your blacklisted characters have special meaning to the regex engine while inside of a character class, then they will need to be escaped.