# Truncate sentence right before a hyphen in PHP

Tags: php

I need to find the way to truncate a title right before the hyphen like this:

```
"This is the title-This is an example"
```

So when it is truncated the title will be like this:

```
"This is the title"
```

(Without the `"-This is an example"` part.)

I think there is a PHP function for that but I didn't find it.

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty trivial if you read the PHP manual. Also, `-` is not called a "slash".

Comment: for the sake of learning, why does a question like this get downvoted?

Comment: @Poe: I'd guess because the OP didn't *try* anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to discard everything after a certain string character in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292380/how-to-discard-everything-after-a-certain-string-character-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a few different methods. My personal preference would probably be `strtok()`, for its least amount of code required and efficiency

---

#### `strtok()`

```
$title = strtok($str, '-');
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/VaAKFrak)

---

#### `explode()`.

```
$title = current(explode('-', $str, 2));
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/DhkmFxj2).

---

#### `substr()` and `strpos()`

```
$title = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '-'));
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/e6VguMNi).

---

#### `strstr()`

If using >= PHP 5.3.

```
$title = strstr($str, '-', TRUE);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CTqbnS).

Comment: That seems easier, I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so then I echo the $title, right?

Comment: @user1116921: You certainly do.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

BTW, a - is a hyphen, not a slash.

Comment: Ok, thanks and sorry for my english and PHP knowledge. I will try the explode function.