# Why the HTML tags are not getting removed even after using strip_tags function in following scenario?

Tags: php, html, arrays, associative-array, strip-tags

I've an array titled `$aMessages`. Actually it's quite a huge array but for your reference I'm printing below only first three elements from it:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [message_id] => 240
            [thread_id] => 43
            [user_id] => 244
            [text] => test msg<div class="mail_attach_image"><a class="group1" href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/04/49c79e88b24a8fff8104909fce19aa3f.png" ><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/04/49c79e88b24a8fff8104909fce19aa3f.png"  /></a><br><a class="mail_attach_image_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_ 2015/month_04/file_49c79e88b24a8fff8104909fce19aa3f.png" >Download</a></div>
            [time_stamp] => 1429695832
            [total_attachment] => 0
            [is_mobile] => 0
            [has_forward] => 0
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_server_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-244
            [full_name] => CampusKnot .
            [gender] => 1
            [user_image] => 2015/03/ae6f1665efc29eb3360d392bbcd183b7%s.jpg
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 7
            [language_id] => �
            [forwards] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [message_id] => 241
            [thread_id] => 43
            [user_id] => 901
            [text] => hi
            [time_stamp] => 1429695875
            [total_attachment] => 0
            [is_mobile] => 0
            [has_forward] => 0
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_server_id] => 1
            [user_name] => profile-901
            [full_name] => Student Campusknot
            [gender] => 2
            [user_image] => 2014/11/b23e023750785c8b5e61ace4d6a202fa%s.png
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 6
            [language_id] => �
            [forwards] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [message_id] => 243
            [thread_id] => 43
            [user_id] => 244
            [text] => textmessage
            [time_stamp] => 1429710052
            [total_attachment] => 0
            [is_mobile] => 0
            [has_forward] => 0
            [profile_page_id] => 0
            [user_server_id] => 0
            [user_name] => profile-244
            [full_name] => CampusKnot .
            [gender] => 1
            [user_image] => 2015/03/ae6f1665efc29eb3360d392bbcd183b7%s.jpg
            [is_invisible] => 0
            [user_group_id] => 7
            [language_id] => �
            [forwards] => Array
                (
                )

        )
)
```

If you observe closely in first element's ['text'] key some HTML code is present. I want to remove this HTML code and keep the text value as it is there (in this case the value ' test msg' only should remain there and all other HTML code should get remove).

So basically what I want is to check for each element's ['text'] key value for presence of HTML code.

If HTML code is present then it should be removed and only the plain text should remain.

For doing this I tried following code but nothing changed :

```
foreach($aMessages as $key => $value) {
  $value['text'] = strip_tags($value['text']);
}
```

Can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to change `$key => $value` to `$key => &$value`

Comment: This will helpful for you 

foreach($aMessages as $key => &$value) {
  $value['text'] = strip_tags($value['text']);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` creates a copy of the array. Your `$value` will not be changed in the original array. Either change the value in the original array or assign `$value` by reference.

Quoting http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede `$value` with `&`. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

Also see [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works)

Regarding your comment

> My issue is the string between HTML anchor tags is not getting ignored.

Yes, `strip_tags` will do what the name implies. It strips tags. But not their content.

[Either use ext/DOM to only fetch the first text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432672/fetching-value-using-domdocument-in-php/29432886#29432886) or [simply cut off everything after the first `<`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292380/how-to-discard-everything-after-a-certain-string-character-in-php). The first approach takes more code. The latter is less reliable since the text could potentially contain a regular *less than* that is not a tag.

A good trade-off between reliability and amount of code would be to [compare the original string against the stripped string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475437/find-first-character-that-is-different-between-two-strings) and then only return the substring from beginning to the first different character, e.g.

```
$text = substr($string, 0, strspn($string ^ strip_tags($string), "\0"));
```

Note that none of these approaches take into account that there might be text outside tags, e.g. `textMsg<b>foo</b>bar<i>baz</i>end` will just yield "textMsg". If you want "textMsg bar end" use DOM like this:

```
$string = 'textMsg<b>foo</b>bar<i>baz</i>end';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div id="root">' . $string . '</div>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$combinedDirectTextNodes = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('id("root")/text()') as $text) {
    $combinedDirectTextNodes[] = $text->nodeValue;
};
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

echo implode(' ', $combinedDirectTextNodes); // textMsg bar end
```

Comment: The code given in the answer by Aryeh Armon is working fine for me. My issue is the string between HTML anchor tags is not getting ignored. If you read my comment on above answer you'll come to know about the issue I'm facing. I need help for that now.

Comment: The issue I'm now facing is not related to foreach loop execution. It is related to strip_tags() functionality.

Comment: @PHPNut updated my answer to contain links to possible solutions to that issue

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
foreach($aMessages as $key => $value) {
    $aMessages[$key]['text'] = strip_tags($value['text']);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it has one problem for the first element's key ['text'] I got value "test msgDownload" instead of "test msg" only. It's taking the string 'Download' which is present within the anchor tags. I want to ignore this. How should I do this?

Comment: Strip_tags removes the html tags not what it wraps.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should modify the origin array instead of the clone in the foreach loop.
2. You can't use strip_tags() to remove tags and the content inside the tags. strip_tags() only remove the tags.

Try this:

```
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
    if($invert == FALSE) { 
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
    else { 
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
  } 
  elseif($invert == FALSE) { 
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
  } 
  return $text; 
}

foreach($aMessages as $key => $value) {
  $value['text'] = strip_tags_content($value['text']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not wrong then, this'll work for you, if your concerns are towards only getting `test msg` only else using `strip_tags` it will strip all the tags but the rest of data would be there

```
foreach($aMessages as $key => &$value){
    $aMessages[$key]['text'] = substr($value['text'],0,strpos($value['text'],'<'));
}
print_r($aMessages); //Array ( [0] => Array ( [message_id] => 240 [thread_id] => 43 [user_id] => 244 [text] => test msg [time_stamp] => 1429695832 [total_attachment] => 0 [is_mobile] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [message_id] => 241 [thread_id] => 43 [user_id] => 901 [text] => [time_stamp] => 1429695875 [total_attachment] => 0 [is_mobile] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [message_id] => 243 [thread_id] => 43 [user_id] => 244 [text] => [time_stamp] => 1429710052 [total_attachment] => 0 [is_mobile] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: Have you tried my code.